# subfiles inside a subfile using relative paths

Tags: folders, subfiles

Is there a way to use subfiles, in a way that you can compile the middle chapters, let me explain by example.

```
main.tex (root folder)
--Chapter 1 (Chapter 1 folder)
----Section 1.1 (Chapter 1 folder)

Capter 1 is subfile in main.tex
Section 1.1 is subfile in Chapter 1 docment
```

What I can do is that I can build and view every section, and the main.tex, but I cannot build Chapter on its own. The code:

```
%main.tex
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\subfile{chap1/chapter1}
...
\end{document}

%chapter1.tex
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\subfile{chap1/purpose}
...
\end{document}

%purpose.tex
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\section{Purpose}
\end{document}
```

The trouble I am in stems from the relative paths I believe, if I change the subfile in the chapters to:

```
\subfile(../chap1/purpose)
```

I can build the chapter and view it. But then it won't work from the main.tex files. Any idea how to do it right ?

Edit:
If there is a method or command to get the absolute path, I would be able to solve it easily, is there such a thing ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have had the same issue as you.

It is important to note that `\providecommand` only defines `\main` one time which is the first time it is run.

So when providing `\main` in a subfile then it is also provided in `master.tex` and `master.tex` will not redefine it.

That is also why it needs to be done before the document class in subfiles as this is where the `master.tex` code is executed.

If you use `\def\main{..}` instead then it will be overridden every time you include a subfile.

It was solved as:

```
%main.tex
\usepackage{subfiles}
\providecommand{\main}{.} % relative path to master.tex
\begin{document}
\subfile{chap1/chapter1}
...
\end{document}

%chapter1.tex
\providecommand{\main}{..} %Important: It needs to be defined before the documentclass
\documentclass[\main/main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\subfile{\main/chap1/purpose} %Insert relative before file
...
\end{document}

%purpose.tex
\providecommand{\main}{..}
\documentclass[\main/main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\section{Purpose}
\end{document}
```

I hope someone will find is useful.

**Edit:**

One can also solve this by providing \input@path.
This makes the solution work without inserting \main in all path's

```
\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\input@path}{{..}}
\g@addto@macro\input@path{{..}}% append % if you cant override it
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank already handed in my bachelor awhile ago, but its still nice to know, it is perfectly understandable, i just could not see my way out of it :D