# Does subfiles work with memoir?

Tags: memoir, biber, subfiles

I am considering whether to to try to use `subfiles` with `memoir`, `biber`, and `xelatex`. Before I try, I wanted to ask: does this kind of setup work with `subfiles`?

Usually I would just try it myself and see, but [this question on SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308751/biblatex-and-biber-in-a-subfile) has made me hesitate because it suggests that similar setup does not work, then a self-answer, which is marked as accepted, has an "EDIT" that says that it only works to compile the mainfile but not the individual subfiles. But compiling the subfiles is of course the whole point of using `subfiles`.

In other words, what I want to know is whether `subfiles` a robust package that should work with all these different complex packages and software -- or is it really just designed for simple LaTeX documents without automated bibliography, Unicode, or other complications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer to the main question: *Yes, the `subfiles` package will most likely work.* I edited the almost correct answer of *B Hos* to make his example work. The crucial point when using `subfiles` is to ensure that the paths are correct; here it meant to wrap the command `\subfix` around the bibliography file. [See the docs](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/subfiles/subfiles.pdf) for details.

The problem in [the old thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308751/biblatex-and-biber-in-a-subfile) is actually not a `subfiles` problem but related to the specific TeX editor used: How to tell it what the current main file is, for typesetting and displaying? Otherwise, posts older than two years are probably not useful anymore, as both, LaTeX and the subfiles package, changed considerably in October 2020.

**General remark:** Do you have a good reason for using the `subfiles` package? To structure the source of a large document, the most robust way is still to use `\input` (and to a lesser extent `\include`), and to comment/uncomment these `\input` statements as needed. The main document may look like

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\input{mypreamble}
\begin{document}
\input{sections/introduction}
%\input{sections/problem}
%\input{sections/solution}
%\input{sections/conclusion}
\end{document}
```

to typeset the introduction only. With a really large document, the included files may consist of `\input`s themselves. Since `\input` is built in to (La)TeX, it works seamlessly with all packages and all TeX tools (including editors).

Comment: In my setup, I have a `sections/` directory where I put an ever-changing collection of files, each one added or renamed as I draft and move around sections or chapters of a book. I then have a simple script to generate a file with the necessary `\input` commands for everything that is in `sections/`. So it is trickier to just comment things out -- or rather that commenting is overwritten each time I write the script. But you're probably right that it may nevertheless be the simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

I used TeX Studio, default compiler and XeLaTeX both worked.
In addition to the example below I tried the article class.

Main.tex:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber, 
    style=authoryear-icomp, 
    sorting=nyt]{biblatex}

\usepackage{subfiles} 
\addbibresource{\subfix{bibliography.bib}}

\title{Subfiles package example}
\author{}
\date{ }

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \section{Introduction}
    \subfile{sections/introduction}
    \section{Second section}
    \cite{Potter2017}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Introduction.tex

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum
    \cite{Anderson2018}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

## Edit

bibliography.bib:

```
@article{Potter2017,
    author={Potter, Joe},
    title={Marmots},
    journaltitle={Alpine Journal},
    volume={3},
    number={2},
    year={2017},
    pages={40--43}
}

@article{Anderson2018,
    author={Anderson, Joan},
    title={Waterwheels},
    journaltitle={Engineering},
    volume={9},
    number={1},
    year={2018},
    pages={92--101}
}
```

Comment: Were you able to get the bibliography to work when compiling the subfile? You didn't include `bibliography.bib`, so I added it in the same directory as `main.tex`. But then running `biber` (after running `xelatex`) on `introduction.tex`, I get "ERROR - Cannot find 'bibliography.bib'!"

Comment: @AlexRoberts I corrected the example, it should work now.